# DolphinDB: Query to return most recent data

Tags: sql, time, dolphindb

I have a database table with a TIMESTAMP column.

I want to write a SQL statement that will return the most recent data.

For example, I want to get the last hour records using a query.
Please see the SQL statement below:

```
where time >= now() - 3600000
```

This will show the most recent data in the last 60 minutes.

But what if I want to fetch the previous week/month/year records from the database table?

Is there any efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Try **temporalAdd()** function;

Fetch last hour records:

`` Where time >= temporalAdd(now(),-1,`h) ``

Fetch last week records:

`` Where time>=temporalAdd(now(),-1,`w) ``